# What's a proper way to set the name attribute for a dynamically added select tag?(Laravel Blade)

Tags: php, laravel, dom-events, laravel-blade

I work on an order creation view in Laravel Blade. An order comprises either one or many services, so I have an "add service" button, which runs a script to add a select tag to the page.

I can create a counter variable and do something like this:

`select.setAttribute("name", "service_" + number_of_distinct_services);`

Should the `number_of_distinct_services` variable be a PHP variable that I increment in the view and then pass to the JS function? **If not, then how do I do it?**

If I do that, I don't completely understand how I will access these variables later in the controller. **Is it done by using strings as variable names?**

**Can I somehow wrap all of these choices up in an array instead of them being separate variables?**

View code excerpt:

```
<form action="{{ route('orders.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <select class="form-select" id="services" name="service_1">
            <option selected>Choose a service</option>
            @foreach ($services as $service)
                <option value="{!! $service->id !!}"> {!! $service->service_name !!}</option>
            @endforeach
            <input type="number" style="width: 150px;" name="" id="" value="0" min="0" max="100">
            <a type="button" style="width: 150px;" class="btn btn-success" href="#" onclick="addSelectForServices({{ json_encode($services) }}, {{ $number_of_distinct_services }});">Add a service</a>
        </div>
    </select>
    <div id="addable_fields">
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function addSelectForServices(services, number_of_distinct_services){
    var container = document.getElementById("addable_fields");
    var select = document.createElement("select");

    select.setAttribute("class", "form-select");
    select.setAttribute("name", "service_" + number_of_distinct_services);
    
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.innerHTML = "Select...";
    newOption.setAttribute("selected", "");
    select.appendChild(newOption);
    for(let i = 0; i < services.length; i++)
    {
        newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.setAttribute("value", services[i].id);
        newOption.innerHTML = services[i].service_name;
        select.appendChild(newOption);
    }

    container.appendChild(select);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```

Comment: Depend on what you will do with those variables later? Do you need to access specific ones or just all of them? If all of them, you can assign an incremented value ($i), or put them in an array. Then it is easier to find the max number of records ($i) or loop the array.

Comment: Can you provide code examples of what you currently have?

Comment: @milenmk Later in the controller's store function I'm planning to attach these chosen services to the created order instance, so I need to all of these variables. I don't exactly understand, at what point(or where) do we put them in the array?

Comment: @Peppermintology I added some code samples. I have that PHP $number_of_distinct_services variable that I pass to my JS, but I can't seem to grasp how to increment it on button click. Do I need to use AJAX to be able to increment the variable?

Comment: Is there a reason for using multiple `select` elements rather than just defining your current `select` element as allowing `multiple` options?

Comment: @Peppermintology the way I'm trying to do this seems more convenient to me from user-experience perspective